Сокращение слова "страница": стр. или с
Вот что мне самому удалось найти по этому вопросу:

Есть ГОСТ 7.12-93 от 1995 году, в котором даётся только вариант "с.". Справочник Мильчина, ссылаясь на этот ГОСТ, даёт такую же рекомендацию.
При этом Грамота в 2010, ссылаясь на орфографический словарь РАН, отвечала, что оба варианта допустимы. Словари сокращений тоже обычно дают оба варианта.

Являются ли источники, на которые я здесь сослался, всё ещё актуальными? По-прежнему оба варианта сокращения считаются равноправными или всё же какой-то из них стал более предпочтительным?

Самый полный словарь, им обычно пользуются:   https://sokr.ru/search/?query=страница  Там оба варианта.  Предпочтительнее тот, который к стилю текста подходит, об этом надо думать.

ГОСТ Р 7.0.12-2011 - СОКРАЩЕНИЕ СЛОВ И СЛОВОСОЧЕТАНИЙ

